# How a thread x with a unique request is marked ready after is blocked?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

A thread requests a read of a file and becomes blocked awaiting completion of that request.

Sometime the disk completes that request.
What code and how does it know which thread to wake up?

How that happens on the linux kernel?

Comment: In short, r/w request to the block device contains also the thread, which should be awoken when request is completed. In long... the question is quite "too broad" for Stack Overflow format. You may read some resource about how a block device driver interacts with other parts of Linux kernel.